# Script hangs because page loads too quickly?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am seeing a problem with either Robot Framework or Selenium Webdriver in cases where a link or element is clicked that results in a page transition. The script hangs & stops running as if it's trying & failing to click the requested element/link even though the window successfully processed the click. Manually refreshing the Webdriver window to reload the page kick-starts the script and it resumes from there.

The only thing I can think is there is a delay between when Selenium or Robot executes the command and when it's able to listen for an HTTP response from the browser, and the page is loading *before* Selenium is ready to listen for it. This is running on an intranet and so the page load times are pretty quick. I've never seen the issue happen when running the same script on a SauceLabs VM since the tunnel between us & them adds a lot of latency.

Assuming my theory is correct, what do I do about it (apart from the obvious running over a slower connection)? Setting a delay in Selenium only slows down the execution and doesn't really affect the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fluent wait...

```
  public static WebElement fluentWait(final By locator, RemoteWebDriver rwd){
  Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(rwd)
          .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

  WebElement foo = wait.until(
          new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
              public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                  return driver.findElement(locator);
              }
          }
    );
    return  foo;              
    };
```

This will poll every 2 seconds and wait a maximum of 30 seconds

in your Test you then wait for an element eg fluentWait(By.className("home"), driver);
before you can click or verify text etc

Comment: I already have the capability of waiting for an element to appear before clicking/verifying, etc. This is not the problem I'm having. The problem I think I'm having is, in selenium terms, click() expects a response from the browser, and the response happens before it can listen for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Set Selenium Implicit Wait  60
Set Browser Implicit Wait  60
```

The number 60 is the seconds to wait by default for both selenium/browser.